# Why java8 server JRE do not contain server specific tools like jstack, jmap, jvisualvm, jstat

Tags: java

From [oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/server-jre8-downloads-2133154.html)

> The Server JRE includes tools for JVM monitoring and tools commonly
>   required for server applications, but does not include browser
>   integration (the Java plug-in).

From the server side tools usage, the list of tools which tops for monitoring are jstack, jvisualvm, jstat, jconsole; all are missing from the jdk/bin of server jre bundle.

Any idea of the rational behind this bundling.

## Edit

This is the case only for "server jre 8". For "server jre 7" all these tools where present.

Comment: I think that's because the tools you mentioned are a development tools. They are not intended to be used in production environment, this tools are for development, debugging and analysis only.

Comment: @alexeymalev, These tools are used for monitoring the java process for any issues. For eg: In production we use jstack to analyze server hangings and jvisualvm for any monitoring/profiling. By the description i felt that we should be taking "server jre" to fulfill these needs.

Comment: Well, I think you are free to use any tools that fits, but it seems Oracle doesn't agree that such usage should not happen.

Comment: Not sure this question can be realistically answered by someone who does not work at Oracle, the way it is currently worded.

Comment: They're not present in my JRE 7. They're JDK tools.

Comment: @atulsm Because the package itself is designed specifically for deploying java in server environment without any additional fancy overhead (just deploy that is it).

Comment: This package is quite new I think (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u21-relnotes-1932873.html#serverjre). It's a "mixed" version of JDK and JRE. It's called JRE but it contains a directory called JDK. A JRE should not contains the JDK, it's the JDK that should contain the JRE. See this illustration :http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index.html

Comment: Server JRE (7) was introduced April 2013.

Comment: I downloaded server-jre-8u45 for Linux and from the tools you listed, only jconsole is available as a .jar, under `/lib`.

Comment: @EJP They are present in server jre 7, not regular jre 7. But the same is missing in server jre 8.

Comment: If you are using Linux, you probably want to install the corresponding JDK `-devel` package. The devel package contains `jstack`, `jstat` and all others that seem to be missing. In CentOS/RH for example: `yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`

Answer (score 26):

After some research, I have found that many of the "missing" tool functionalities are actually still available.

For example jcmd can do the same and more than jstack. To take a thread dump in severe jre 8, use `jcmd $PID Thread.print`.

jconsole tool functionality is indirectly available, even though jconsole is missing in bin, the jconsole.jar is there in the lib folder and you can execute it using `java -jar lib/jconsole.jar` to get the same old functionality.

jcmd can also be used to get other memory/gc stats. Run `jcmd $pid help` to see more info.

So with these tools, I think it's fine to get the same feature set in server jre 8 as we used to get in server jre 7 and it might be removed from server jre 8 to remove redundancy.

Comment: Beautiful!  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html

Comment: What about jstat? I'm in a serious need to check the metaspace but I'm in your same situation: no jstat on jre 8 server edition :(

Comment: Hi, for example jstat -gc <PID>

Comment: @Phate, for that use jcmd $pid GC.run

Comment: gives "operation not permitted" :( Do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: @Phate, thats probably because you are not running the command as the user which runs the java process. run "ps -ef | grep java", find the user and "su $user", then run "jcmd $pid GC.run".

Comment: Just in case someone is struggling to run jcmd as the process user without shell access, if sudo is enabled, the command you're looking for is `sudo -u $user jcmd $pid GC.run`

Answer (score -2):

Use jattach

```
apk add --no-cache jattach --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/
```

Refer : https://dev.to/jarekprzygodzki/generating-jvm-memory-dumps-from-jre-h8c